# Having issue with slidedown function

Tags: javascript, jquery, row, slidedown, prepend

## Problem

Can't get `prependTo()` and `slideDown()` functions work together.

## Short

Please take a look at the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/5CxPr/53/

Press "new" to see what happens

Am I missing something?

## Detailed

Here is JS code

```
function newrow(elem){
    if($("#"+elem+"s").is(":hidden")){
        $("#"+elem+"s").slideDown("slow")
    }
    $('<tr />').addClass(elem).append(
        $('<td />').text('new row')
        ).prependTo("#"+elem+"s").slideDown("slow");
            
}

$(document).ready(function() {
       $(".new").click(function() {
        newrow($(this).attr("id").replace("add_",""))
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use tables. They don't like being animated.

[Use divs instead](http://jsfiddle.net/5CxPr/57/)